# strcpy not working correctly with dynamically allocated char arrays

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void cpy(char *str) {
    //char buffer[16];
    char *buffer = malloc(16 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(buffer, str);
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
       printf("buffer[%i]: %c \n", i, buffer[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    //char large_str[256];
    char *large_str = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
       large_str[i] = 'A';
    }
    //large_str[255]= '\0';
    cpy(large_str);

    return 0;   
}
```

When I compile and run this in Cygwin I get `buffer[0]` to `buffer[299]` to be mostly empty. I did get some trash around blocks of indices, like `buffer[252]` to `buffer[264]`, and `'A'` from indices `0` to `23`. But when I change it to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char buffer[16];

void cpy(char *buffer, char *str) {
    //char *buffer = malloc(16 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(buffer, str);
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
       printf("buffer[%i]: %c \n", i, buffer[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    //char large_str[256];
    char *large_str = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        large_str[i] = 'A';
    }
    //large_str[255]= '\0';
    cpy(buffer, large_str);

    return 0;   
}
```

Then it works perfectly. `buffer[0]` to `buffer[255]` contain `'A'`, and the rest is empty. Why the difference?

Comment: You allocated 16 chars, so why do you expect it to work with 256 chars?

Comment: In both examples the call to `strcpy()` invokes undefined behaviour by accessing memory beyond the 16th element after where `buffer` is pointing to. So the `printf()` in both examples tell you nothing as with undefined behaviour already invoked anything may happen.

Comment: Because I'm trying to understand how it would work with buffer overflow. If a hacker was using that exploit they would need it to copy the information they intended it to past index 16, right?

Comment: @alk: Moreover, since the source string is not null-terminated, it will be undefined behavior regardless of the destination.

Comment: @Josh: May be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two major problems, both leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

1. You don't terminate the string in `large_str`. That means all string function which looks for the terminator (like `strcpy`) will go out of bounds.
2. You copy a very large string (even larger without the terminator) into a small buffer. That means you will go out of bounds of the small buffer.

Remember that C doesn't have any kind of bounds-checking.

Also note that these problems are in *both* your programs.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the strcpy Linux man page

> The strcpy() function copies the string pointed to by src, including the terminating null byte ('\0'), to the buffer pointed to by dest. The strings may not overlap, and the destination string dest must be large enough to receive the copy. Beware of buffer overruns!

You are allocating a 16 sized buffer and trying to fill it with a 256 sized buffer. strcpy will go over the bounds of that buffer causing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have a buffer OverFlow in this line:

```
strcpy(buffer, str);
```

I would suggest determining how many bytes you are going to pass to the buffer in memcpy by using this syntex:

```
memcpy(dest, source, numOfBytes)
```

**Note:** memcpy won't stop when in meets a NULL in the string. only when it finish to copy all the Bytes you wanted. However, you can set it up in a way that will help you not create an overFlow

exe:

```
memcpy(buffer, str, 16);
```

This would help you avoid creating a dynamic memory corruption which can lead to an unexpected result or even crash your program.